# Display:hidden not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, responsive-design, mobile-safari

for some reason the display:hidden property isn't working for an image of mine in mobile safari (or at least on my phone's Safari).

Here's the HTML:

```html
<img src="imac.png" id="finalImg" />
```

And the CSS

```css
#finalImg{
max-width:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}
@media only screen and(max-width:800px){
img#finalImg[style]{
display:none !important;
}
}
```

As you can see I tried overwriting the "display:block", but for some reason it still renders in safari. The page with the actual page can be found here: http://david-hong.com/mamute.html

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your selector: `img#finalImg[style]`. You `<img>` does not have a `style` attribute. Just use `#finalImg` in the media query.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 @media only screen and(max-width:800px){
        img#finalImg{
        display:none !important;
        }
```